# Explosion breaks up into pieces

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm following along with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29yfS-icS3M) but my explosion looks like this. [image: this] The explosion breaks up into pieces. I would like it to look similar to the video where big bubbles form in it.
Explosion from the video looks like this.
[image: Image from the video]

I used same settings as the video.

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awjcm4xmwVVDKaaCFC28HeT3l8n15lwh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have uploaded the blend file to google drive. Using blender 3.0.1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awjcm4xmwVVDKaaCFC28HeT3l8n15lwh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by turning initial velocity higher.
[image: Initial Velocity Image]
[image: Explosion Image]

Answer (score 0):

i am using Blender 3.2 and i am not sure whether you mean that: I also didn't find the "color mapping", but you can use this:

[image]

Check grid display and move the white slider to pos 0.006 (so faaaaar to the left), then you get something like this:

[image]